# Order functions by speed of their asymptotic growths

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

We are given list of functions. Task is to sort it by the speed of their asumptotic growth in ascending order.
[image]

Yes, it's a homework. I already spent some solid amount of time calculating limits.
I used following rule: $f(n) = O(g(n)) $ iff $\space \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(n)} {g(n)} < \infty$

As result, I got following sequence:

```
11 14 5 12 6 15 7 1 9 8 13 2 17 3 4 16 10
```

I doublechecked my result, but autograder keeps telling me that result is erroneous.
I would appreciate if you guys take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ordering of functions 8 and 9.

Comment: ...I almost started pulling hair out of my head with that problem;